# How to restructure form json data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

How can I restructure form data returned by `serializeArray()`
to a more desirable structure?

So now I have:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"email8",
      "value":"test1@test.com"
   },
   {  
      "name":"password8",
      "value":"pass1"
   },
   {  
      "name":"email9",
      "value":"test2@test.com"
   },
   {  
      "name":"password9",
      "value":"pass2"
   },
   {  
      "name":"email10",
      "value":"test2@test.com"
   },
   {  
      "name":"password10",
      "value":"pass3"
   }
]
```

I want it to be:

```
{  
   "test1@test.com":"pass1",
   "test2@test.com":"pass2",
   "test3@test.com":"pass3"
}
```

I dont mind if this is done in PHP or Javascript.
Here Is an image of the form if it helps:[image]

*Update:*
Here is what I'm doing that might be better to change:

```
$user = WebmailAutologinUser::find(1);
$emails = array(
"test1@test.com" => "pass1",
"test2@test.com" => "pass2",
"test3@test.com" => "pass3" );

foreach ($emails as $email => $password) {
    $user->autoLoginAccounts()->create([
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
    ]);
}
```

Its using eloquent to inset the array into the db.

So `email` and `password` is a column in the db.

Comment: write custom serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible approach, using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var arr = [{"name":"email8","value":"test1@test.com"},{"name":"password8","value":"pass1"},{"name":"email9","value":"test2@test.com"},{"name":"password9","value":"pass2"},{"name":"email10","value":"test3@test.com"},{"name":"password10","value":"pass3"}],
    res = arr.reduce((s,a,i) => (i % 2 ? s[arr[i-1].value] = a.value : null, s), {});

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: If you have to ask if your answer is proper, maybe wait before posting it?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Is is that really bad that I'm asking OP if it's exactly what he wants? Waiting for his response to remove/improve my answer. Anyways, this kind of behavior like you present at this moment isn't helpful, at all. Rather destructive.

Comment: Close but that returns
```
{  
   "email8":"admin@e17pumphouse.org.uk",
   "password8":"pass",
   "email9":"hireing@e17pumphouse.org.uk",
   "password9":"pass",
   "email10":"abdullah.seba@e17pumphouse.org.uk",
   "password10":"pass"
}
```

Comment: @AbdullahSeba Specify in your question what exactly do you need. I assumed that you are looking for an object containing the `name` property as it's **key** and the `value` property as it's **value**.

Comment: @Kinduser I dont want the name at all. I want the email as key and the passwords as value. The name is there cuz thats how `serializeArray()` works. The same as my second json shows.

Comment: @AbdullahSeba Look at my edit, this is what you expect?

Comment: @Kinduser woops and the wrong json there.

I want it like the second json from the post.
`{  
   "test1@test.com":"pass1",
   "test2@test.com":"pass2",
   "test3@test.com":"pass3"
}`
 I have updated the post with an image

Comment: @AbdullahSeba So you are interested only in **even** entries inside that array? Because only them actually possess the `pass` value.

Comment: @Kinduser even? not sure what you mean.
I just need something that will be like the second JSON.
Will update my post with a bit of php that might be changeable to suite a better solution.

Comment: @Kinduser Have a look now at the post see if it helps further :)

Comment: @Kinduser Thats what I want but for some reason its misses the second key and value from the form `var arr=  $(this).serializeArray() ;`
works with hard-coded array.

Comment: So it gets the first an last but not middle.

Answer (score -2):

```
function test()
{
//alert("Hi");
var text = '[{"name":"email8","value":"admin@e17pumphouse.org.uk"},{"name":"password8","value":"pass"},{"name":"email9","value":"hireing@e17pumphouse.org.uk"},{"name":"password9","value":"pass"},{"name":"email10","value":"abdullah.seba@e17pumphouse.org.uk"},{"name":"password10","value":"pass"}]'

json = JSON.parse(text);

var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];

    if(obj.name.startsWith('email')){
        key = obj.value;
      i++;
      var obj = json[i];
      if(obj.name.startsWith('password')){
        result[key] = obj.value;
      }
    }


}

console.log(result);

}
```